# XNA .fbx Model import, invisible texture

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, rendering, textures

i'm trying to import a .fbx model into my xna project. It works fine, but the texture is black. If i try to add a texture manually to it, the object just becomes invisible. Am i missing something?

```
using System;
using AR_Framework.Graphic.Camera;
using GoblinXNA;
using GoblinXNA.Graphics;
using GoblinXNA.SceneGraph;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using XNAModel = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Model;

namespace AR_Framework.Graphic.Model
{
    class Modelimporter
    {
        public TransformNode import(String Model, Vector3 coordinates, int scale)
        {

            try
            {
                XNAModel xnaModel = CameraWindow.ContentLoader.Load<XNAModel>(Model);
                GeometryNode node = new GeometryNode(Model);

                Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[xnaModel.Bones.Count];
                xnaModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);
                xnaModel.CopyBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

                IModel model = new GoblinXNA.Graphics.Model(transforms, xnaModel.Meshes);
                node.Model = model;


                TransformNode modelNode = new TransformNode();
                modelNode.Translation = coordinates;
                modelNode.Scale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);

                modelNode.AddChild(node);
                return modelNode;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Model not found!");
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with using models in XNA, but I'm guessing it would be useful to see the model rendering code.

Comment: what is the format you use, I'm working with XNA using .fbx models. I use 3dMax to export them with texture it self.